# Python: Checking if X number of lists contain a certain element

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm very new to python and trying to figure out a good way to check several sublists for a certain statement. I thought that

```
if A in list:
#Do this
```

Would do what I wanted but it doesn't seem to be working. This does however work and achieve what I want.

```
if A in list[1] or A in list[2] or A in list[3]...so on:
#Do this `
```

The problem is that the number of lists depend on a chosen input variable, so I want something in the style of

```
input=B
if A in list[range(0,B)]
#Do this
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: If `#Do this` is a function this would be a trivial thing using a for loop iterating over the lists in range 0, B;Is `#Do this` a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if any(A in lst for lst in lists):
```

Note that I renamed your variable to `lists`, it's a bad idea to name it `list` as it clashes with a built-in function of the same name.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! Solved it perfectly. Just so I understand what this does, it checks if there are any A in a list for the lists in lists? If that makes any sense..

Comment: @JoakimNyholm it check it the `A in lst` condition is met _at least_ once. If it finds a match, it stops and returns `True`. Otherwise, it'll return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

There's two different questions here, I'm not sure which one you're asking for.

If you've got a list of lists to check, you should be able to check each of them in turn:

```
  for each_list in list_of_lists:
      if A in each_list:
         do_something()
```

If you want to generate the lists to check based on input, `range` already creates what you want:

```
if A in range(0, B): 
    do_something()
```